# Create 'marl' background: striped effect in Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, background

I am trying to create the effect in the below 2 photos for a t-shirt.

[image]

[image]

How can that background (maybe called marl) be created in Photoshop or Illustrator?

I've have limited success creating it with **Filter > Sketch > Graphic Pen**.
What would be the best method. If possible something which could easily allow me to change the colours in it, on an ongoing basis.

Comment: Hi mmc501, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site or the SE model in general, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help] to get you up to speed. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: A practical comment (which is why its not an answer), the T shirt printer is not going to like any complex bitmap so after Photoshop you would be better creating a vector (VectorMagic better than Illustrator for bitmap to vector). Then he can print in a single ink. Also, I tend to go for a patterned fabric base shirt (i.e. a cotton with marl in it) and print graphics over the top - simpler, more reliable if you repeat run.

Answer (score 12):

In Photoshop, make a brush like this

[image]

Then in the Brush Settings, add the following settings

- Brush Tip Shape: Spacing 10%
- Shape Dynamics: Size jitter 70%
- Scattering: Scatter 360%, count 2
- Noise

[image]

Note: my screen recorder seems to mess up the brush cursor, so please ignore that.

Comment: How can i make the initial brush that shape?

Comment: @mmc501 I used the Pen Tool to draw a shape, then filled it black.

Answer (score 7):

**Illustrator**

- From an ellipse, create a **Scatter Brush**

[image: Scatter Brush]

- Make two vertical paths and apply this brush on each one separately

[image: brush]

- Select both paths, apply a stroke color
- Select both paths, **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend Options** > **Specified Steps** = increase the number of steps

[image: Blend]

- Select the *Blend*, **Menu Effect** > **Stylize** > **Feather**

[image: Feather]

- Make a rectangle on top of the *Blend*
- Select the *Blend* and the *Rectangle*, **Menu Object** > **Clipping Mask** > **Make**
- Using the **Direct Selection Tool** click the mask edge to select it and fill it with color

[image: pattern]

Comment: Nice technique. How heavy, byte-wise does this become? Same question for 'oh-my-graphics-card-is-starting-to-sweat-wise' ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is a randomised 'Clouds' pattern that has been scaled down vertically but not horizontally. In Photoshop:

1. Create a document as wide as you want the pattern to be, and twenty times as high;
2. In that document, choose the darkest you want the pattern to become as your foreground colour; and the lightest colour you want as background colour;
3. Choose <kbd>Filter > Render > Clouds</kbd>;

[image]

4. Select all contents of the current layer with <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>;
5. Choose <kbd>Image > Free Transform</kbd> (or press <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>);
6. In the control bar on top, find the 'H' value (100% now) and make sure the link it has with 'W' (width) is broken (click the link icon to switch between linked and broken);
7. Click in the H value's field and key in a value around 5% and press <kbd>Return / Enter</kbd>;
8. Crop your image as needed (<kbd>Image > Crop</kbd> with the selection still active works great) or copy and paste the result as needed.

[image: marl result in Photoshop]

In practice, I'd advice you to take black and white as the original colours (as I did in the example), so you can tweak the colours using a gradient map layer later.